# Read specific lines from text file using Item reader in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to read attached text file which is not formatted, from line START-OF-DATA TO END-OF-DATA and ignore all other lines in the file.[sampleText file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD1o8.png)

I created my reader like below and it was not working as my file is unstructured and it contains extra line before actula data

```
public CustomFlatFileItemReader<MyBean> reader() {
    CustomFlatFileItemReader<MyBean> reader = new CustomFlatFileItemReader<MyBean>();

    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<InterestRate>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|") {{
            setNames(new String[] { "name", "refKey1","refKey2","refKey4","refKey5","refKey6","refKey7"});
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {{
            setTargetType(MyBean.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
```

Comment: can you share a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have done so far and the issues you're facing? Also, do you mind sharing the input as text instead of an image?

Comment: When I use text it is automatically converting into the different format without line brakes so I attached an image

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom reader (that could extend `FlatFileItemReader`) for that. This reader should skip lines until it reads "START-OF-DATA", return every line after that until it reads "END-OF-DATA" where it returns `null`.

The lines in between are regular pipe separated values, so you can use the same configuration you shared to map fields to your domain object.

Comment: Thanks for the response @mahmoud , I am trying to implement ItemReader instead of extending FlatFileItemReader, which approach is best?

Comment: By extending the `FlatFileItemReader`, you can reuse much of the logic of parsing and mapping fields, etc. But you can create a custom reader as well.